# Create single object using two array

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays of same length

```
ids = [123, 456, 789, ...., 999];
names = ['foo', 'bar', ... , 'zzz'];
```

I want to create an array like

```
[ {id: 123, name: 'foo'}, {id: 123, name: 'bar'}, ..., {id: 999, name: 'zzz'} ]
```

I am trying to avoid `forEach` if possible.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `map` okay?

```js
ids = [123, 456, 789, 999];
names = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'zzz'];

result = ids.map(function(_, i) {
    return {id: ids[i], name: names[i]}
});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: This was gonna be more or less my answer as well. Just wanted to add a disclaimer for the OP to be weary that with two independent arrays, there is a likelihood that one array could be unequal in length to the other, in which you may end up not creating every pair as a literal, or worse, the `ids` array has more elements than `names`, which will cause an error of the index being out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use any higher-order functions, then just do this:

```
var objects = [];
for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
  objects.push({id: ids[i], name: names[i]});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for `forEach` here. Use `map` which is similar to `forEach`.

```js
var ids = [123, 456, 999];
var names = ['foo', 'bar', 'zzz'];

var result = ids.map(function (currentId, index) {
  return {
    id: currentId,
    name: names[index]
  };
});

console.log(result);
```

The `forEach` version would look like this (notice how similar they are):

```js
var ids = [123, 456, 999];
var names = ['foo', 'bar', 'zzz'];

var result = [];
ids.forEach(function(currentId, index) {
  result.push({
    id: currentId,
    name: names[index]
  });
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code uses `foreach` but you dont need to handle it. I hope this will work for you.

```js
    ids = [123, 456, 789, 999];
    names = ['foo', 'bar', 'zab', 'zzz'];
    
    result = ids.map(function(_, i) {
        return {id: ids[i], name: names[i]}
    });
    
    console.log(result)
```